# Using `package://` in URDF with ROS2

Tags: ros2, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**How is `package://` in an URDF file resolved in ROS 2, i.e. what do I need to put there so that the files are found?**

---

Some context:

With ROS 1 I was using `package://package_name/meshes/file.stl` in the URDF file with a directory "meshes" at the root of the package.  This was working fine using the devel space.

Now with ROS 2, I am installing the meshes with

```
install(DIRECTORY meshes DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

so they end up in `install/package_name/share/package_name/meshes`.

Unfortunately, when loading the URDF, they are not found.  I assume, I need to adjust the `package://...` part.  I already tried `package://package_name/share/package_name/meshes` without success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370075/using-%60package://%60-in-urdf-with-ros2/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2021-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2 packages are found using the .ament resource index ([design doc here](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/master/ament_cmake_core/doc/resource_index.md)). First there needs to be a marker file in the `packages` folder.

Second, I assume you're doing an isolated build with colcon (which is the default), in which case your package's install prefix is `install/package_name`. Add another `share` and `package_name` and the URI `package://package_name/meshes/file.stl` should resolve to `install/package_name/share/package_name/meshes/file.stl`, which means it should have been installed to `share/package_name/meshes`.

## How it works:

The package `resource_retriever` is used by other packages to resolve `package://` URIs. It calls [ament_index_cpp::get_package_share_directory()](https://github.com/ros/resource_retriever/blob/3ae40bd03f29cee2ad1a3ee83861ff35bc832f2e/resource_retriever/src/retriever.cpp#L114). That's [implemented here](https://github.com/ament/ament_index/blob/d9bdf844c907118165d850535ed383c2dbf0afd9/ament_index_cpp/src/get_package_share_directory.cpp#L27). In short, it returns a string like `<package prefix>/share/<package_name>`.

In your example I assume you're doing an isolated build with colcon (which is the default), in which case your package's install prefix is `install/package_name`. Add another `share` and `package_name` and the URI `package://package_name/meshes/file.stl` should resolve to `install/package_name/share/package_name/meshes/file.stl`, which means it should have been installed to `share/package_name/meshes`.

## How to create a marker file

How to create a marker file depends on the build type in the package.xml

```
  <export>
    <build_type>...</build_type>
  </export>
```

### Build type: ament_cmake

`ament_cmake` packages automatically install the marker file. You only need to call `ament_package()`.
It happens inside `ament_package()`, but not in a straightforward way. It [invokes extensions](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/5730e2e6b64185ee91cca9f24ee2e2e0324e3324/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake#L66), which calls an extension [ament_cmake_index_package_hook()](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/5730e2e6b64185ee91cca9f24ee2e2e0324e3324/ament_cmake_core/cmake/index/ament_cmake_index_package_hook.cmake#L16) because [ament_cmake_core registered it with itself](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/5730e2e6b64185ee91cca9f24ee2e2e0324e3324/ament_cmake_core/ament_cmake_index-extras.cmake#L24-L25), which ultimately calls [ament_index_register_package()](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/5730e2e6b64185ee91cca9f24ee2e2e0324e3324/ament_cmake_core/cmake/index/ament_index_register_package.cmake#L21-L30). I don't know why `ament_package()` goes through the extensions instead of calling `ament_index_register_package()` directly.

### Build type: cmake

I don't know of a plain CMake package example to link to, but this should work.

Create an empty file with the same name as your package (example below assumes it's in a folder called `resource` adjacent to your CMakeLists.txt), then install it to `share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/resource`.

```
install(FILES resource/my_package_name
 DESTINATION share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/resource
)
```

### Build type: ament_python

Python packages install the markerfiles themselves.

Create an [empty file with the same name as your package in the repo](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/tree/4ddeff3e75f910af8da4549c7065c761e9398cf4/ros2node/resource), then install it using the [`data_files` argument of `setup()`](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/blob/919f55c939c90aefce0b19a4c77d265dc22988f5/ros2node/setup.py#L10-L14).

```
data_files=[
    ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
        ['resource/' + package_name]),
],
```

## Related questions

https://answers.ros.org/question/367328/

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2021-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2021-01-25**:
Thanks for your elaborate answer!  So apparently I was already doing everything correctly.  And indeed, after doing a clean rebuilt, it is not working without further changes... I have no idea what the problem was last week.

**Comment by [concaveros](https://answers.ros.org/users/82598/concaveros/) on 2021-08-28**:
In my case, adding `<gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/.."/>` to my package.xml similar to the [turtlebot3-description-reduced-mesh](https://github.com/aws-robotics/turtlebot3-description-reduced-mesh/blob/ros2/package.xml#L17) package fixed the issue.